# How do I create a Django queryset equivalent to a SQL query using the OR operator?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, I know using `filter` with multiple arguments gets translated into SQL `AND` clauses. From the Django Book:

> You can pass multiple arguments into
>   filter() to narrow down things
>   further:
>
> ```
> >>> Publisher.objects.filter(country="U.S.A.", state_province="CA")
> [<Publisher: Apress>]
> ```
>
> Those multiple arguments get
>   translated into SQL AND clauses. Thus,
>   the example in the code snippet
>   translates into the following:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, name, address, city, state_province, country, website
> FROM books_publisher
> WHERE country = 'U.S.A.'
> AND state_province = 'CA';
> ```

How do I create a Django queryset that gets translated into SQL `OR` clauses? For example:

```
SELECT id, name, address, city, state_province, country, website
FROM books_publisher
WHERE state_province = 'AZ'
OR state_province = 'CA';
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

using the Q operator available in django.db.models

IE:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Publisher.objects.filter(Q(state_province="CA") | Q(state_province="AZ"))
```

Have a look in the docs here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. I think I've read that section of the docs, but I didn't find it today. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, have used it many, many times so it popped straight up in my head. :)